# Prove $P(A-B)\subseteq(P(A)-P(B))\cup\{\emptyset\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Prove that $P(A-B)\subseteq(P(A)-P(B))\cup\{\emptyset\}$

**Attempt**: Suppose $X\in P(A-B)$ then $X\subseteq A-B$, which means $X\subseteq A$ and $X\cap B=\emptyset$. Then, $X\in P(A)$ and $X\notin P(B)$. Therefore, $X\in(P(A)-P(B))$. This leads to $X\in(P(A)-P(B))\cup\{\emptyset\}$.

**Question**: Is this correct? If not, can someone give me the answer or point my mistakes out? Thank you!

**Note**: $P$ is the power set, not probability.

Comment: $X \subseteq A- B$ is not the same that $X \subseteq A$ and $X \nsubseteq B$.

Comment: $X \subseteq A - B$ is equivalent to $X \subseteq A$ and $X \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: Your first argument should be correct. The answer to your second question is obvious: $\emptyset$ is contained in both P(A) and P(B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X \nsubseteq B$ might lead that some elements in $X$ are in $B$ but not all, but what we want is that none of the elements of $X$ are in $B$ and thus we need the second statement $X \cap B = \phi$.